# VS2010 doesnot pick up file from resources folder

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010, relative-path

I am required to parse a text file in my VS project in mfc in c++. The text file is supposed to be a part of the entire `exe` product. For that purpose, I placed the text file in my resources folder and set the path in my code as:

```
char fileName[] = "../myFile.txt";
```

The problem I'm facing is that VS doesn't find this file in its Resources folder. I added the file in the project file, but that just gave me a corrupt file error. However, the file access works if I provide the absolute path to the file in my code i.e. `"C/abc/myFile.txt"`

I need the code running on all machines, hence need some method to get VS to read this file using a relative path. Can anybody please provide some assistance? I am a newbie and have tried all that's in my knowledge.

Answer (score 0):

Actually, if it's a resource file it should be copied over to the bin folder, which means your fileName should just be:

`char fileName[] = "myFile.txt";`

if that doesn't work then, you might need to change the properties of your myFile.txt to ensure it does get copied over with the build process.

Comment: thanks for your reply! how do i change the properties of my file so that it gets included in the build process? I searched around and there is a setting in VS in the properties that lets you specify the build action. I dont see any such setting in my VS. All I see in the properties panel for my textfile is: Name , Content (true/false) , File Type, Full Path, Included in Project (true/false)

I have specified 'Included in Project' as true. But still no difference

Answer (score -1):

Here you can find an answer for your question: http://www.cplusplus.com/forum/general/54255/

Comment: Link only answers are discouraged because links vanish over time.  Please give a brief summary of the answer here.